# Hide only numbers in EditText for pin-code (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, pin-code

I have EditText in myApp with this TextWatcher and numberSigned input type:

```
TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        codeinput.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String text = s.toString();
        text = text.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        if (text.length() > 4)
           text = text.substring(0, 4);

        String newText = "";
        for (char c : text.toCharArray())
           newText += c + " ";
        text = newText.trim();

        String substring = "_ _ _ _".substring(text.length());
        text += substring;

        int length = text.replaceAll("([ ]?[_])+$", "").length();

        codeinput.setText(text);
        codeinput.setSelection(length);
        codeinput.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
};
```

When i change input type from numberSigned to numberPassword - all symbols in my EditText is hidden, i want to hide only numbers. How can i do it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid that password type field hides all characters and you can't do anything with that

but consider using [setLetterSpacing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float)) and don't use spaces (method available since API21)

if you need lower API support and you still want to use `numberPassword` then you have to set up 4 `EditText`s - use `editText.requestFocus` for jumping to another/next `View`. or you may keep one `EditText` with `numberSigned`, but exchange during text entering all digits to asterisks (keeping digits in some separated value, as `editText.getText` will return you only asterisks)

Comment: Minimum API support in my app - 23, target - 29

Comment: so use `android:letterSpacing="0.2"` in XML or Java/Kotlin method from my answer. and remove all spaces from your `String`. your `EditText` needs 4 digits so allow and post in there 4 characters only

Comment: Hot can i add mask "_ _ _ _"?

Comment: just use `"____"` instead of `"_ _ _ _"`. `setLetterSpacing` will add spacing between digits in this field